# How to reenable the built in wifi again after I used an external antenna?

Tags: wifi

So I'm building an autonomous boat with my Pi (3B), to which I connected using [an external USB wifi adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32829125691.html) (which had a better range). I used the [trick as described here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1047531&sid=c3d788b93f92368ff2d5419700810d6f#p1047531): I simply blacklisted the built in wifi by adding the file `/etc/modprobe.d/brcmfmac.conf` which contained `blacklist brcmfmac`. This worked great.

I now added a 2G/GPRS module to the boat, so I can connect to it over the mobile network, so I don't need the bulky wifi adapter anymore. To achieve that I removed the file `/etc/modprobe.d/brcmfmac.conf`, and then physically removed the adapter from the USB port. After a reboot the built in wifi doesn't seem to work though. When I connect the wifi adapter again the pi connects to my network again. So it seems the pi still connects to the wifi using the external adapter. I repeated this several times, with the same result.

Does anybody know why the pi continues to use the external antenna instead of the built in wifi antenna? How can I make it use the built in antenna again? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

I pasted the output of `ip link` when the adapter is connected below:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:ba:30:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:1c:a8:7f:7e:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

To run the same command when the adapter is not connected I opened `screen` on the terminal, and than ran `sleep 20 && ip link` and quickly disconnected the adapter. I pasted the output below. I'm not sure whether that is the same output after a reboot with the adapter unplugged though.

```
$ sleep 20 && ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:ba:30:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 3
    link/ppp
```

[EDIT 2]

I now added the line below as a cron and then rebooted the pi with the adapter unplugged.

```
@reboot sleep 10 && ip link > /home/pi/iplinkresult.txt
```

Afterward a while I plugged in the wifi adapter again and ssh'ed into it, to find that the contents of the file `iplinkresult.txt` where the same as I pasted above.

[EDIT 3]

The result of `rfkill list`:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: with the wifi dongle disconnected, what is the output of `ip link` - what is the output when the wifi dongle is connected

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yes, I'm referring to one of these: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32829125691.html

Comment: yeah, I removed that comment and added a comment asking for information :D

Comment: @JaromandaX - I added the results of `ip link` to the question.

Comment: can you check that the line `blacklist brcmfmac` doesn't exist in any other file in `/etc/modprobe.d` folder

Comment: @JaromandaX - It's a raspi 3B and I already ran `sudo ack brcmfmac /` to search for any occurrance of the string anywhere on the system.

Comment: fair enough - just checking - so I guess there's no brcmfmac in the output of `lsmod` ... how about the output of `dmesg | grep -i brcmfmac`

Comment: @JaromandaX - Both `lsmod | grep -i brcmfmac` and `dmesg | grep -i brcmfmac` gave no output.. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: what's the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: before you disabled the onboard wifi, had you ever used it successfully?

Comment: I take it that's the output when the wifi dongle is connected?

Comment: Yes, that's the output of `rfkill list` when the adapter is connected. And yes I used the wifi succesfully before adding the adapter. Do you want the result when it is disconnected as well?

Comment: no, it really looks like the onboard wifi just simply doesn't exist!! - if you look at the output of `dmesg` (without the grep) - anything stand out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a systematic testing procedure, rather than a shotgun approach.

Try a fresh Raspbian on a new SD Card

If this works the hardware is OK,
if not you have probably damaged the Pi.

Only if WiFi works on an unmodified OS try software fixes. As always the BEST solution is to restore from your backup.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, as this is how troubleshooting should be done!

Comment: Well, turns out you seem to be right. I installed a fresh Raspbian on a separate sd-card and with that the wifi also doesn't work without the external wifi adapter. I guess the internal wifi is simply broken. I'm unsure how something like that can happen though. But yeah, time to move on. I was planning on moving this to a Raspi Zero W anyway, to save on battery. Thanks for all your help. Eitherway, I learned a lot from it.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the logic. With default setup you have two interfaces:

```
eth0
wlan0
```

With an additional GPRS dongle you should see:

```
eth0
wlan0
ppp0
```

With your setup you see without dongle:

```
eth0
ppp0
```

and with dongle:

```
eth0
ppp0
wlan0
```

Do you see it? In the first case **wlan0** is always available, in your case it is **ppp0**. It seems something is making **wlan0** to **ppp0** in your case. Adding the dongle will use the first free device name and that is **wlan0**. So I suggest to look what is renaming your internal WiFi interface **wlan0** to **ppp0**. You fiddled with (un)loading the WiFi driver following an obscure tutorial you have linked. There is no need doing such things. As you will find in `/boot/overlays/README`, adding a line `dtoverlay=disable-wifi` to `/boot/config.txt` will just do that.